# Python Mock Function and Import Mock

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

In my test files, I would like to mock a helper function that I have contained within a module.  I am able to 'successfully' (ie no compile or run time errors as everything is linked properly) mock the function, but the mock does not trickle through to the class I am testing.

I have looked into dependency injection, but I am not exactly sure how to inject my module which only has one function mocked for now.  Eventually I plan on mocking almost all of the functions; I just want to get a baseline working first.

Here is what I have so far

```
class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('modules.MyHelperModule.helper_function')
    def test_simple(self, mock_hf):

        my_obj = MyObj()

        # internally, this class imports HelperModule 
        # and the method calls helper_function with 1
        my_obj.do_something()

        mock_hf.helper_function.assert_called_with(1)

        return
```

The assert command is failing and reporting that the method was never called. I am assuming the mock never makes it through to my_obj.

I understand that I could create a flag in the init method of MyObj like testing=False and import modules accordingly, but how could I import the module that was mocked only in the test files?  This is the approach I am thinking about right now, but I am open to other implementations that get me the same result.

In response to Daniel Roseman's comment,

In MyOBJ, I have the following line

```
from modules.HelperModule import helper_function
```

However, I am getting the error

```
ImportError: No module named modules
```

My patch line now looks like

```
@mock.patch('MyObj.modules.HelperModule.helper_function')
```

Any help is always appreciated; Thank you!

Comment: Read this: [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: Continuing my own research and I just came to the same article!  Thank you.  Do you know a more detailed version than the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that mock_hf is not what you want to patch.
try with:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):


def test_simple(self):
    with patch('modules.MyHelperModule.helper_function') as mock_hf:
        my_obj = MyObj()
        my_obj.do_something()
        mock_hf.assert_called_with(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Daniel Roseman's comment to my original post, the issue was with where I was patching.

I should have been patching MyObj.helper_function.  Additionally, I had, in the **init**.py, a from MyObj import MyObj.  This caused me to only be able to reference the MyObj class in my tests, but I needed to overwrite the helper_function for the whole file.  I had to remove that line.